# Como crear nodos vacios en c# XML

Tags: c#, xml, xdocument

Estoy creando tratando de crear un archivo xml. y me dieron el formato del como debe de ser creado.

```
<VENTAS>
 <VENTA>
  <CorreoRespaldo/>
  <FechaDeVenta>15/04/2019 12:23:13 p. m.</FechaDeVenta>
 </VENTA>
</VENTAS>
```

este es el codigo. intente en agregarle un `string.Empty` pero solo crea un espacio.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    //(1) the xml declaration is recommended, but not mandatory
    XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

    //(2) string.Empty makes cleaner code
    XmlElement element1 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "VENTAS", string.Empty);
    doc.AppendChild(element1);

    XmlElement element2 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "VENTA", string.Empty);
    element1.AppendChild(element2);

    XmlElement element3 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "CorreoRespaldo", string.Empty);
    XmlText text1 = doc.CreateTextNode(string.Empty);
    element3.AppendChild(text1);
    element2.AppendChild(element3);

    XmlElement element4 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "FechaDeVenta", string.Empty);
    XmlText text2 = doc.CreateTextNode(DateTime.Now.ToString());
    element4.AppendChild(text2);
    element2.AppendChild(element4);

    doc.Save("C:\\document.xml");
```

Y este es el resultado.

```
<VENTAS>
  <VENTA>
    <CorreoRespaldo> </CorreoRespaldo>
    <FechaDeVenta>15/04/2019 12:23:13 p. m.</FechaDeVenta>
  </VENTA>
</VENTAS>
```

El nodo queda vacio. pero quisiera que la segunda etiqueta de cierre quede en una sola etiqueta

```
<CorreoRespaldo/>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenes que setearle NULL en lugar de string Empty ,quitando los child

```
XmlElement element3 = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "CorreoRespaldo", string.Empty);
element2.AppendChild(element3);
```